# All audio/video is stuttering

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, media

I am running Windows 10 Pro x64.
Sometimes, without any obvious reason or trigger, all audio and video playback - no matter if it's youtube, VLC, Spotify, the Windows sounds - starts stuttering uniformly and does not stop until reboot.
I have installed the latest graphics, chipset and audio drivers - no change.

[edit] WPR result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/za54vkkkq3opsqm/Result.rar?dl=0

Comment: download the WPRP file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rl4r784kvnhypf/Multimedia_WPRP.WPRP?dl=0 and store it on your HDD. Now open a cmd as admin and run **wpr -start "FullPathTo**Multimedia_WPRP.WPRP**" capture 1 minute of the stuttering. After this, run **wpr -stop C:\Result.etl** Zip the Result.etl (to reduce the size), upload the zip to OneDrive, create a share link and post the file here.

Comment: I've added the link. I had to wait that long until it occurred again.

Comment: from the trace I see no DPC issues, so the stuttering doesn't come from this. I can see some CPU usage of the SYSTEM process relates to Memory Compression. Do you have Memory pressure when you see the issue? The trace doesn't show all memory data

Comment: No, I have 8GB RAM and no VMs whatsoever. There should be plenty of space.